# how to get the router navigation end url only for the first navigation change

Tags: angular

```
this.router.events.subscribe(
  event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) console.log(event.urlAfterRdirects);
  }
);
```

this adds the code to run for all the route changes. I want the only first route change. I tried something like this. It worked but don't know how it impacts

```
this.myEvents = this.router.events.subscribe(
  event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          console.log(event.urlAfterRdirects);
           this.myEvents.unsubscribe();}

  }
);
```

Comment: There's no one way to do this, your solution will work fine

Comment: Smokey Dawson: how does the unsubscribe inside a subscribe work?Is it risky to use this way?